# How do I populate the AjaxControlToolkit combo box with JQuery using a webservice

Tags: jquery, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit, populate, data-retrieval

Is it possible to populate the AjaxControlToolkit ComboBox with jQuery using a webservice. I want to do this to get away with update panels containing large response data. With this I also want to get the selected data in code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible because AjaxControl Toolkit creates separate HTML elements to generate the list options